# Why are some owners prevented from seeing the version history for a file in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, version-history

We have a team sharepoint library which currently has two Owners and a number of members and visitors.  Our problem is that the "version history" functionality seems to be applied inconsistently - for example, I'm one of the owners and when I click on the ellipsis to the right of that file, I can see and access the version history for that document.  But when one of the other owners of the file does the same thing, the "version history" action doesn't even appear.  How can I troubleshoot this?  When I view the file I see the dialog shown in the image.  But when another (explicitly-defined) owner of the folder does the same, the "Version History" entry in the dialog is not there at all.

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that permissions haven't been modified for the document itself.

For example, when you say that a user has been granted ownership of a folder, perhaps the folder permissions were changed and a specific user was added? If that is the case, then perhaps the following sequence of events occurred:

1. file1 was shared with "specific people", which means the file now has its permission inheritance "broken"
2. file2 exists in the folder, but was not shared
3. the folder's permissions are changed and a specific user was given permissions. Since the file1 is not inheriting permissions, the new permissions applied to the folder do not take effect on file1. File2 was never shared, so it is still inheriting permissions, so the changes to the permissions of the folder are reflected in the permissions of the file.

If the above is the case, I'd recommend resetting up permissions and using groups to assign permissions, rather than listing specific users.

Answer (score 0):

Double check whether the user has enough permission on the documents.

Does the user cannot see all documents' version history?It is by designer that We can view the version history on a document but not on a folder. Let the user choose another document and compare the results.

Open the library in classic mode, check whether the user can see the version history button:

[image]